# Allocate more RAM to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, memory, performance

I’m using the 64-bit version of Chrome. I have:

- 32 GB of RAM
- an 8 Core i7 CPU, and
- an SSD

When I’m browsing on a page with large chunk of data (such as Facebook) and when scrolling for too long, the page become ridiculously slow and unresponsive. The same thing happens when scrolling too long on Messenger chats, as if Chrome is running out of memory and I’d have to open another tab.

Is there a way to allocate more RAM? the old Maximum tile method is no longer available.

Comment: "is their a way to allocate more RAM?" More than 8GB, No, More then Chrome is requesting, No.

Answer (score 0):

You cant allocate RAM to an application in general.  An application will use RAM as it is programmed to, which might not necessarily be ideal.  Since you have 64 bit Chrome on a 32GB system, Chrome has access to all of the memory, but due to its programming and the Facebook website, it is not going to use much.